# copy data after when a user select it

Tags: php, mysql

thank you all in advanced for at least reading my question..
I've three tables in my database ( Accounts , Advertising , MyJobCart) to allow users to select jobs in Advertising section from my web.

My question is, how do I copy the selected jobs information to my 'MyJobCart' table including the user ID. so if the user picked multiple jobs, it will appear under his/her name ???

and 'MyJobCart' has exactly the same field as Advertising except two columns which is status column and ID which is related to 'Account'. and I crated a relationship with 'Account' table using the ID as a foreign key

```
[Account Table]
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+-------+
| StudentID    | FirstName   | LastName | Email   | 
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+-------+
| 0            |    xxxx     | xxxx     | xxxx    |  
| 1            |    xxxx     | xxxx     | xxxx    |          
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+-------+

[Advertising Table]
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+-----------------+
| JobID        | Name        | description| numberOfJob     | 
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+-----------------+
| 0            |    xxxx     | xxxx       |     xxxx        |  
| 1            |    xxxx     | xxxx       |     xxxx        |          
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+-----------------+

[MyJobCart Table]


 +--------------+-------------+------+-----+-----------------+---+--------+
 | No       | StudentID   | JobID | Name| description|numberOfJob| status | 
 +--------------+-------------+------+-----+-----------------+-----+------+
 | 0        |    xxxx     | xxxx  |     |xxxx        | xxxx      |  xx    |
 | 1        |    xxxx     | xxxx  |     |xxxx        | xxxx      |  xx   | 
 +--------------+-------------+------+-----+-----------------+------+-----+
```

These Are the Tables I've and as u notice MyJobCart has a StudentID and it's linked to Account table..

I just would like to know the query that I can user to let user when he/she select job, it copy it over under their StudentID

I've been trying to figure out how to do it, but I've got no luck ..

Comment: Why don't you create a job table, and reference the ID in the advertising and MyJobCart tables? This way you don't have to copy data, you can insert a new row and delete the old advertising one.

Comment: What you have tried and where you stucked ?

Comment: yeah now, it's kinda too late, I have many tables, is there any way to do it wth having tables like this way I built this database ?

Comment: I've like 11 tables like Food, Cleaning, and so on, they all have the same fields

Comment: is it possible to make it work although I've built the database in the way I did ?

Comment: _“I've like 11 tables like Food, Cleaning, and so on, they all have the same fields ”_ – that should be __one__ table, that has an additional column to store what type/field of job the record represents.

Comment: if I've to change the whole database it means I've to change the whole code again for each function  :( is it possiable to make it work without having to change the whole coding

Comment: Rajdeep Paul, would it be possible to make it work , with the design i made ??

Comment: @aymanko First of all, always consider [normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) while designing your database. In my opinion *Account* and *Advertising* table is fine but in *MyJobCart* table only `<No, StudentID, status>` are required. Since *StudentID* attribute of *MyJobCart* table is linked to *StudentID*  attribute of *Account* table and *No* attribute of *MyJobCart* table is linked to *JobID*  attribute of *Advertising* table, a `JOIN` query would be enough to get all the required data.