# Design my database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I've to do my whole project from scratch, and I'm ok with it, just don't want to do the same mistake ..

I've two tables, on is ( Jobs ) and ( Categories ) , I need to link the categories to the jobs, is it one-to-one relationship ? I want to link them together
so I Can do edit and delete and add jobs from my web-site using PHP

```
[Jobs Table]
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+-----------------+
| JobID        | Name        | description| numberOfJob     | 
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+-----------------+
| 0            |    xxxx     | xxxx       |     xxxx        |  
| 1            |    xxxx     | xxxx       |     xxxx        |          
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+-----------------+



[Categories Table]
+--------------+-------------+
| JobID        | Name        | 
+--------------+-------------+
| 0            |    xxxx     | 
| 1            |    xxxx     |        
+--------------+-------------+
```

these are my tables, I would appreciate your help guys

Comment: Can you have more than one category per job?

Comment: You'd want a 1-to-many relationship.  In this case, 1 category to any number of job postings.  I'd create a "categories" table with "id", "category_name", and then create a "jobs" table, with your current columns and add a "category_id" column, which would contain the id of the relevant category table row.  This of course yields you only one category per job, otherwise more complex coding/design is required.

Comment: next-to-exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35087761/copy-data-after-when-a-user-select-it

Comment: create a field called category_id in Jobs table. link id from Category Table to Job tables category_id. You now have one-one relationship

Comment: yeah, u cab have many jobs in each catagory..

Comment: is it  one-to-one , OR one-to-Many  ???

Comment: [Visual Representation of SQL Joins - CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Categories is a lookup table, and every job belongs to one category:

```
Jobs
----
JobID
CategoryID
JobName
JobDescription
JobNumber

Categories
---------
CategoryID
CategoryDescription
```

To display all data from Jobs table, your SQL would be:

```
SELECT * FROM Jobs
```

You could also sort the results by any column, such as:

```
SELECT * FROM Jobs ORDER BY JobDescription
```

...or show just certain data like so:

```
SELECT J.JobDescription, C.CategoryDescription
FROM Jobs J
LEFT JOIN Categories ON J.CategoryID = C.CategoryID
ORDER BY J.JobDescription
```

Comment: and if each job belongs to one (and only one) category, you have a 1-to-many relationship (one category can have multiple jobs).

Comment: would u mind sir, to write one query how to dispay all data from Jobs table ? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: @aymanko you seriously need to get on a tutorial website and learn this stuff and not have people do all your work